# Facebook returning a 206 response only from a determined server

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I'm trying to post a feed using Facebook javascript API (FB.ui). When I post the feed, the image field appears empty.

Of course I've tried the URL from the [example provided by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg and it works fine. Then I downloaded this image and uploaded to my server and tried again and got nothing.

Using the facebook debugger, the facebook example image returns a 200 message, and the same image from my server returns a 206 message, which I believe is the reason why it's not showing in the feed dialog.

This is the Graph API output from debugger:

```
{
   "id": "530885910309390",
   "url": "http://www.zx-works.com/img/f8.jpg",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "http://www.zx-works.com/img/f8.jpg",
   "updated_time": "2013-06-01T18:48:22+0000",
   "created_time": "2013-06-01T18:23:58+0000",
   "is_scraped": true
}
```

Question is: what can possibly change from one server to another to facebook not get the image correctly? Is something I can do to fix it from my server side? It's running Apache 2.2.24. Someone runned into this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses ipv6 to scrap your website. Is your DNS set to ipv6? Did your server controlpanel (like directadmin) allow ipv6 access?
Otherwise, contact your hosting company to answer these questions and you'll be fine!

Comment: This was excactly the case with my websites. I fixed the problem adding the ipv6 records in Direct Admins DNS management as you said. Good find!