# Facebook return 206 response code from AWS S3 images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on Amazon S3, but when i used these images on my site and share this with Facebook, facebook share no work, and if i use facebook lint, Facebook says "response code 206".

How i can fix this problem in amazon s3?

i upload this example image:
https://tyr.s3.amazonaws.com/example.jpg

i need fix this problem to show image preview on facebook.

Thanks

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: IPv6 issue maybe? Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876178/facebook-returning-a-206-response-only-from-a-determined-server?rq=1

Comment: Since your bucket appears to be in São Paulo, the preferred urls would be `https://tyr.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/example.jpg` or `https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/tyr/example.jpg`.  Do those perform any differently?

Comment: Why is 206 a problem?

Comment: because facebook dont show my images from website... so, for me is a great problem, really heavy problem

Comment: @Igy facebook says "website http response code 206", but when i use curl, or another tool, this return http response code 200.

Comment: 206 isn't a problem; Facebook's crawler is not asking for the entire contents of the page (I think it's just 40K?), so your server will respond with 206 - if there's some problem with Facebook crawling your page, the 206 isn't the cause of it